# Convert html string in Vue Component (PROPS)

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I am getting html string from api server to show the data in Vue component.

However, I cannot convert br tag, nbsp;, or such strings which is in the actual response from the api server.

What I want to see:
Hello
World

What I am seeing in the screen right now:
Hello'htmlbrtag'World

Is there any way I could solve this problem?

```
<template>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="sw-lead-box">
            <span class="sw-title">{{ banner.title }}</span>
            <span class="sw-tags">{{ banner.content }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img__shadow"></div>
        <img class="sw-bg" src="../../static/images/main/m-swiper-bg1.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        banner: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

banner.title and banner.content are the items that correspond to the issues I mentioned above.

Is there any Jquery's html() function for vue?

Comment: Try using `v-html`
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html

Comment: Found out that v-html is an answer for my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my easy question. haha @Hiren